# How to destroy objects of Message listener in Spring Kafka?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I was following this

[Creating KafkaListener without Annotation & without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120255/creating-kafkalistener-without-annotation-without-spring-boot)

I have an API, so whenever the API is called a new container is created with a new message listener. The listener will fetch messages of certain offsets and then it will be paused. After that, I don't need it. But when the API is hit many times lots of objects will be created. I want to destroy the useless objects.

I was thinking of when a listener is idle for some time, then I can destroy it.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

CODE

```
public class Listener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware implements ConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        // pause if certain offset received
    }

}
```

This is the container

```
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> getContainer(String topic, int partition, long offset) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, partition, offset));
        ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProperties());
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> kafkaMessageListenerContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, containerProperties);
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(new Listener());
        return kafkaMessageListenerContainer;
}

private Map<String, Object> consumerProperties(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }
```

Comment: KafkaMessageListenerContainer implements the [Lifecycle stop() method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html#stop--).

Comment: I do not recommend creating containers manually like that - see my answer.

Comment: @ChinHuang So, this will destroy the container object as well?

Answer (score 0):

Creating containers like that will disable many features (e.g. event publishing).

It would be better to use Boot's auto-configured `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` to create the containers.

```java
/**
 * Create and configure a container without a listener; used to create containers that
 * are not used for KafkaListener annotations. Containers created using this method
 * are not added to the listener endpoint registry.
 * @param topicPartitions the topicPartitions to assign.
 * @return the container.
 * @since 2.3
 */
C createContainer(TopicPartitionOffset... topicPartitions);
```

When you no longer need the container, simply call `container.stop()`.

Comment: Hi Gary, How should I replace "KafkaMessageListenerContainer" by "ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory", can you give me a sample code?

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950229).

Comment: I have changed my code to whatever you mentioned in the link. It's working fine. I am not sure about @EventListener. How will I know it is working?

Comment: You don't need that if you have some other criteria for stopping the container; that question was about how to dynamically create a container and stop it when there are no more records to read. For it to work, you need to configure the `idleEventInterval` as shown in the answer.